# Solving $T(n) = 3T(n-1) + 2$

Tags: recurrence-relation

I am trying to get better at solving recurrence relations, so I am making my own simple relations and try to solve them. I have made the following recurrence:

$$T(n) = 3T(n-1) + 2, \quad\quad T(1) = 1$$

My work at solving it:
$$\begin{align*}
T(n) &= 3^2T(n-2) + 3*2 + 2 \\ 
     &= 3^3 T(n-3) + 3^2*2+ 3*2 + 2 \\
     &= 3^4 T(n-4) + 3^3*2 + 3^2*2 + 3*2 + 2 \\
    &= \dots \\
  &= 3^k T(n-k) + 3^{k-1}*2+3^{k-2}*2 +\dots+3*2+2 \\
 &= 3^k + 3^{k-1}*2+3^{k-2}*2 +\dots+3*2+2 \\
&= 3^k +[\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} 3^i*2 ] + 2
\end{align*}$$

where $k = n - 1$.

I guess the Big O would be exponential since the above would be less than $3^n$ which is $O(c^n)$?

I am stuck on how to finish this and find out what the time complexity is in Big O notation.

Comment: You may want to be more careful and slower. `T(n) = 3 [3[3[3T(n-4) + 2] + 2] + 2] + 2 = 81 T(n-4) + 80`.

Comment: Please try to compute a few more explicitly. See if you can find any pattern.

Comment: You mention time complexity, but I don't see any algorithm to compute the time complexity for.

Comment: I have changed the three last lines, is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Your question is a rather basic one. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599) which cover some fundamentals you seem to be missing in detail. Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific problems you encountered. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Apass.Jack hinted at in the comments, you were a bit careless when multiplying and adding everything. Here is a hint for you:
$$\begin{align*}
T(n) &= 3T(n - 1) + 2 \\
&= 3^2 T(n - 2) + 2 \cdot 3 + 2 \\
&= 3^3 T(n - 3) + 2 \cdot 3^2 + 2 \cdot 3 + 2 \\
&= 3^4 T(n - 4) + 2 \cdot 3^3 + 2 \cdot 3^2 + 2 \cdot 3 + 2 \\
&= \cdots \\
\end{align*}$$

When solving these types of recursion, it usually helps *not* to simplify expressions (e.g., "$2 \cdot 3$" helps you a lot more than multiplying and writing just "$6$"). This is the only way you can manage to recognize more complicated patterns.

Bonus exercise once you are done with this: Try and solve the more general recurrence $T(n) = a T(n-1) + b$ for arbitrary $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thank you I see I did forget to multiple the 2's by 3 too, I have only multiplied 3 with the other 3's I will update my answer and get back

Comment: I have changed the three last lines, is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

Let us add $1$ to both sides of your recurrence:
$$
T(n) + 1 = 3T(n-1) + 3 = 3(T(n-1) + 1).
$$
This shows that
$$
T(n) + 1 = 3^{n-1}(T(1) + 1),
$$
and so
$$
T(n) = 2 \cdot 3^{n-1} - 1.
$$